# T-SQL sum on decimal results in integer

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, decimal, converters

Alright, T-SQL isn't acting as I would expect.
Look at this:

```
SELECT SUM(DEBET),SUM(CREDIT)
CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),
    CASE WHEN SUM(DEBET) - SUM(CREDIT) > 0.00
        THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),DEBET))) - CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),CREDIT)))
        ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),0.00)
    END
) AS DEBETSALDO
FROM OTHERTABLE
```

`DEBET` and `CREDIT` in `OTHERTABLE` both are of type decimal; `DEBET(decimal,null)` according to the tooltip.

The result is...

```
DEBET      CREDIT  DEBETSALDO
6817.07    0.00    0
```

Why and where, if DEBET and CREDIT are interpreted as decimals, does SQL convert my whole shebang back to integer in this select statement?
Maybe add a few more converters?

**EDIT**

I just changed

> SELECT DEBET, CREDIT

into

> SELECT SUM(DEBET), SUM(CREDIT)

To emphasize where the problem lies. The results stay the same.

Comment: PS. the chance that I am being retarded is more likely, I know :)

Comment: I assume this isn't your original query as you're missing the `group by`. However if I try the similar thing I don't see the same behaviour. Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: you actually don't need all that `convert`-s. If the expression inside `SUM` is `decimal` than return type should also be `decimal`

Comment: @SeanCoetzee No it isn't the original SQL, but there is basically a group by on one varchar fields in the table, no other fields are being selected.
DEBET and CREDIT are both decimals data types. There's really not that much else going on here.

Comment: @ArturUdod I know, but the SUM's tooltip tells me that `SUM(ALG.DEBET)` aka `SUM(DEBET(decimal,null))` returns INT. It just doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Could you perhaps post the table definition?

Comment: I also get a decimal result when I run the posted code (with corrections to make it actually run since you're still missing a comma. Not much else to do without table definition and the actual query being used.

Comment: I've post my answer, thanks for making me double check the table definition @SeanCoetzee, but there's no way I could have expected this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

Apparently when you convert a `decimal(11,2)` to a `decimal(9,2)` leads to precision loss.

Sorry, I should have double checked that.
But nevertheless, `6817.07` should fit inside decimal(9,2), right?

Thanks for the help.